# $\forall f:R\to R, \exists M>0\land$ an open set $U\ne \emptyset$ in $R$ s.t. $\forall u\in U, \exists$ a sequence $x_n$ in $R$ s.t. $|f(x_n)|\le M$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For any real valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$, it is to be shown that there exists an $M>0$ and a non empty open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$ such that for any $u$ in $U$, there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $x_n\to u$ and that $|f(x_n)|\le M$.

This statement is true for continuous functions as suppose that $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, then take $U=(1,2)$ and $M:=\sup f[1,2]$.

I am having difficulty though in proving this for *any* function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. I don't have any idea in taking this forward *directly* so I tried with contradiction without any success.

Suppose on the contrary that *for every* $M>0$ and *for every non empty* open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$, there exists a $u\in U$ such that for any sequence $x_n\to u$, $|f(x_n)|>M$.

$M$ and $U$ can be chosen arbitrarily so it follows that $f$ is unbounded on every non empty open set. I'm stuck here. Any hints on how to take it forward? Thanks.

Comment: Since there are functions unbounded on every interval, your original statament might as well be false.

Comment: [Finite at every point but unbounded on every interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360491/942722)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The hints so far are encouraging you to think this might be false.*

As an aside, questions like this are very curious.  As you point out continuity (often assumed) makes this easy enough.  But here is a statement true apparently for a completely arbitrary function.  The first instance of this was in the early 20th century.  W. H. Young and his wife G. C. Young were studying cluster sets for functions and (to their surprise) established a number of theorems that were true for completely arbitrary functions.  That was probably the very first such case and they did remark on it.

Here is a "proof" maybe.  Always worth checking.  (This poster might need more coffee.)

1. Fix an integer   $m$  and let $E_m$ denote the   set of all points  $u$   for which there is at least one sequence  $x_n  \to    u$  and for which
   $|f(x_n)| \leq  m$.
2. This set is closed.  If   $e $ is a limit point of $E_m $
   then  arbitrarily close to  $e$  are points from   $E_m$.
   For each integer $n=1,2,3,\dots $ choose a point  $e'$  in   $E_m$   with
   $|e-e'|< \frac1{2n}$.  Then choose a point  $x_n$ that
   satisfies   $  |e'-x_n|< \frac1{2n}$ and with $|f(x_n)|\leq m$.  (If there were no such points then $e'$ violates the condition to belong to $E_m$.)
   Then $x_n\to e$ and $|f(x_n)|\leq m$,  proving  that $e$ is a member of  $E_m$.
3. Now every point of $ \mathbb R$  must belong to at least one member  of the sequence
   $\{E_m\}$.    In fact if $|f(u)|\leq m$ then the sequence $x_n=u$ has the right property.
4. The Baire category theorem asserts that one of these sets contains an open interval  $U$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the nice historical background that you gave. In $(2)$, shouldn't you consider a symbol like $e_n$ to denote $e'$?

Comment: @Koro  Yes.  Label it as $e_n$.  The way I wrote it *can* be misinterpreted to mean that $e'$ has this property for all $n$.  However, I wouldn't have deducted any marks.  The only danger in notation is that you might, later on, forget that $e'$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying to understand $(2)$: Let's denote $e'$ by $e_n$. Since $e_n\in E_m,$ there is a sequence $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^\infty$ that converges to $e_n$ and that $|f(x_k^{(n)})|\le m$. There is some $k_n$ such that $x_{k_n}\in (e_n-1/n,e_n+1/n)$. Now the sequence $(x_{k_n}^{(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ has the property that $|x_{k_n}^{(n)}-e_n|<1/n$ and $|f(x_{k_n}^{(n)})|\le m$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Koro Correct.  Keep it simple as possible however.